# sort order in sql with 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

```
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| ID | Name | sortorder | overridesortorder |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 1  | kkkk | 4         | null              |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 2  | yyyy | 3         | null              |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 3  | zzzz | 2         | 4                 |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 4  | gggg | 1         | 3                 |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
```

I need to display the order like below, sorting the table with above two sort order columns:

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| ID | Name  | sortorder | overridesortorder |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 1  | kkkk  | **4**     | null              |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 3  | zzzz  | 2         | **4**             |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 2  | yyyy  | **3**     | null              |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 4  | gggg  | 1         | **3**             |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please limit your DBMS version tags. There are things that will work on SQL Server 2014 that won't work on SQL Server 2008. Nothing that matters for this question, but still a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the maximum value of the two columns and order by it with that

```
SELECT ID, Name, sortorder, overridesortorder,
(SELECT Max(o) 
FROM (VALUES (sortorder), (overridesortorder)) AS value(o)) as order_value
FROM [TABLE] ORDER BY order_value
```

Comment: The example always has the override higher, but there is no guarantee there.

Comment: i have another rows. Both rows(sortOrder,Overridesortorder) values are null. I need to display remaining rows order by Name column. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
order by coalesce(overridessortorder, sortorder) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking is

```
select * 
from table
order by isnull(overridesortorder, sortorder) desc, overridesortorder
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Name, sortorder, overridesortorder 
FROM t
ORDER BY COALESCE(overridessortorder, sortorder) DESC, sortorder DESC;
```

This will combine the two columns, using the override where it is not null, then sort order where it is null, and then sort the result based on the original sort order column to break ties. If you want to break ties based on the override, you just switch that second sort.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding few more rows

in this case if the sortorder and overridesortorder is null i need to display order by Name

```
ID  Name    sortorder   OverriderSortOrder  order_value
3   zzzz    2   4   4
1   kkkk    4   NULL    4
2   yyyy    3   NULL    3
4   gggg    1   3   3
5   hhhh    NULL    NULL    NULL
6   bbbb    NULL    NULL    NULL
7   jjjj    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   cccc    NULL    NULL    NULL
```